# How to connect strings from an array in java

Tags: java

I'm creating a bukkit plugin and one of its features is to show the plugins on the server, here's my code that handles the plugin listing:

```
for(int i = 0; i < plugins.length; i++){
        String conplugin = plugins[i].toString();
        String[] conplugin2 = conplugin.split(" ");
        if(i + 1 == plugins.length) {
        pluginlist.add(ChatColor.BLUE + conplugin2[0]);
        } else {
            pluginlist.add(ChatColor.BLUE + conplugin2[0] +  ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + ", " );
        }
    }
```

I want to get all the strings from the array (pluginlist) and make one string out of them.

Comment: do you want to create `Strings` from `array`? explain a bit

Comment: @NiteshVirani  I edited the post, I hope it makes some more sense now.

Comment: I belive `plugins` is your array of strings and you want to construct one single string?

Comment: If you want to make so many times changes it will create each and every time newe String in string pool,  instead use StrngBuilder and you can append then all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to construct a String from a String array, you could use a for loop and append the array element to the end of your new string.

```
StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder ();

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
    newString.append (arr [i]);
}
return newString;
```

You could also use a String, but depending on the size of the array of plugins, it would probably be faster to create a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Use a StringBuilder as it is mutable and you can append to it. Strings are immutable hence you can't change it.

You can use the previous StringBuilder example.

Comment: If this question already has an accepted answer, why would you post a new answer that just reiterates the accept answer?

Comment: because it is previously said that a String could be used. But a String is immutable so you can't do that without being a little bit inefficient. That's all knowing that StringBuilder is the way.